# Does dynamic array constructor call delete?

Tags: system-verilog

If I do this:

```
int da [];
...
da = new[2];
...
da = new[1];
```

Have I got a memory leak? Should I have done this:

```
da.delete;
da = new[1];
```

instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to call `delete` unless you have a tool issue. Any time you make an assignment to an array as a whole, the previous array gets deleted.

However, since SystemVerilog has automatic memory management, there is no requirement *when* that memory gets released back to the OS.

Comment: well, however if you did `db = da;` before, then just `da = new;` will not delete the object.

Comment: A dynamic array is not the same as a class.